# Unable to create Dynamic profile page in a blog application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, authentication

**I am working on a MERN blog application and I created a Dynamic URL for Profile page where each individual user can see his profile page when he is logged In**

In my App.jsx file I added Dynamic Route:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

import Home from './pages/Home';
import Write from './pages/Write';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import LogIn from './pages/LogIn';
import Error from './pages/Error';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';

import Layout from './components/Layout';


function App() {
  
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<Layout/>} >
            <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path='newstory' element={<Write/>} />
            <Route path='signup' element={<SignUp/>} />
            <Route path='LogIn' element={<LogIn/>} />
            <Route path='/:id' element={<Profile/>} />
            
          </Route>
          <Route path='*' element={<Error/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>

      <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>

        <ToastContainer className='text-center w-[100px] h-[50px]'/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

**as you can see when user goes to domain.com/:id he should go on Profile.jsx and in Profile.jsx I am making HTTP request to my express backend:**

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect,useState } from "react";

const Profile = () =\> {

const \[data,setData\] = useState(null);
const params = useParams();

useEffect(()=\>{

    const fetchData = async()=>{
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/auth/user/${params.id}`);
        setData(response.data); 
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }
    
    fetchData();

},[params.id])

return (
<div>
<h1\>Profile page goes here\</h1>
<p>{JSON.stringify(data)}\</p>
</div>
)
}

export default Profile
```

This is how my Profile page on website looks like and it is giving me Errors:

[blog website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu8ng.png)

**In my backend route this is how my API end point looks like**

```
route.get('/user/:id', authorizations, async (req, res) => {
try {
const person = await user.findById(req.params.id);
if (!person) {
return res.status(404).send('User not found');
}

    const authIFollow = await user.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { followers: { $elemMatch: { author: person._id } } },
      },
    ]);
    
    person.following = [];
    authIFollow.forEach((user) => {
      person.following.push({ author: user._id });
    });
    
    res.status(200).json(person);

} catch (error) {
console.error('Error fetching user profile:', error);
res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
}
});
```

In the console I am getting and authorization error but I don't know how to fix that?

speaking of which here's my authorization code on server/express side:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config();
//JWT verification Code:
exports.authorizations = async (req, res, next) =\> {
const { authorization } = req.headers;

if (!authorization) {
return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Authorization token required' });
}

const token = authorization.split(' ')\[1\];
req.token = token;

if (token) {
try {
const { \_id } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
req.user = await users.findOne({ \_id }).select('\_id');
next();
} catch (error) {
if (error.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
res.status(401).send('Token has expired, please login again');
} else {
res.status(401).send('Invalid token');
}
}
} else {
res.status(401).send('Not authenticated, invalid token');
}
};
```

Can someone please help me with this? I am stuck on it since a whole day!!

Note:This is my first time asking Question on StackOverflow If I made any mistake in that please forgive me.

#### I tried to make HTTP request as I've shown in the code in Profile.jsx file and I was expecting to  see the data on the page but is giving me Error!

Comment: Are you sure that your app is listening on  port `4000`?

Comment: Also, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: Yes my App is listening to 4000 port